# En vb.net, ¿cómo unir dos variables de tipo short en una variable float?

Tags: vb.net, double, integer, modbus

Soy nuevo por aquí:

Estoy leyendo datos de un autómata programable por medio de modbus tcp. Me entrega datos en variables de tipo int,  16 bits. Sin embargo quiero leer también variables de tipo doble entero. Las variables dobles las obtengo "uniendo" las dos variables de 16 bits, convirtiéndolas en una de 32 bits. ¿Existe alguna instrucción en VB.NET para hacer la conversión?

He encontrado una consulta similar, "Two 16 bit ints to One 32 bit float value", y lo resuelve Eran de la siguiente manera, pero en C, creo:

"You can use Float.intBitsToFloat(int bits) to build a float from the bits of an int.

```
Short high = ... // the high 16 bits
Short low = ... // the low 16 bits
Int combined = (high << 16) | low;
float num = Float.intBitsToFloat(combined);
```

For example

```
Short high = 17530;
Short low = 8192;
```

produces the float 1000.5."

¿Hay alguna manera de resolverlo con VB.Net?

Comment: Mi VB está oxidado, pero no recuerdo que exista un tipo `word`. Aquí https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/ tampoco aparece

Comment: Gracias. He explicado mejor  la pregunta, con un ejemplo que he encontrado en otra consulta similar, no sé editar la pregunta para reformularla correctamente...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese código en VB.net queda algo así:

```
Dim high As Short = 17530
Dim low As Short = 8192
Dim combined = (Convert.ToInt32(high) << 16) Or low
Dim intBitsToFloat As Single = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(combined), 0)

Console.Write(intBitsToFloat) '1000.5
```

Donde `BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(combined), 0)` es el reemplazo natural de `Float.intBitsToFloat`; y por lo menos en VB.net es necesario convertir el valor `high` en `Convert.ToInt32(high)` antes de desplazarlo a la izquierda, porque si desplazamos 16 bits a la izquierda a una variable de 16 bits quedamos donde mismo (es circular), por lo que hay que convertirlo a 32bit para que quede el espacio a la derecha.